# LINQ Query - Custom Output, Group Headers

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to get an custom output using LINQ,
I've made custom class to store data:

```
public class MyFileData
{
// File Name
public string Name { get; set; }
// File's last modification date
public string LastMod { get; set; }
// File size
public long Size { get; set; }
// File extension
public string FileType { get; set; }
}
```

Desired output should look like this:

```
{
    "name": "codeblocks-20.03mingw-setup.exe",
    "lastMod": "13.03.2022 22:57:47",
    "size": 152419674,
},
{
    "name": "somefile.png",
    "lastMod": "16.01.2022 13:16:06",
    "size": 82973864,
},
```

so excluding one of the class properties.
Also I would like to add group headers based on file extensions, so sth looking like this:

```
"type": ".exe",
"files": [
{
    "name": "codeblocks-20.03mingw-setup.exe",
    "lastMod": "13.03.2022 22:57:47",
    "size": 152419674,
    "fileType": ".exe"
},
{
    "name": "DiscordSetup.exe",
    "lastMod": "16.01.2022 13:16:06",
    "size": 82973864,
    "fileType": ".exe"
},
...
]
```

But currently I'm able to return just the list of the class elements, output looks like this:

```
[
{
    "name": null,
    "lastMod": null,
    "size": 0,
    "fileType": ".exe"
},
{
    "name": "setup_becastled_0.2.14_(64bit)_(50823).exe",
    "lastMod": "13.01.2022 13:00:33",
    "size": 281792488,
    "fileType": ".exe"
},
{
    "name": "basic-miktex-21.12-x64.exe",
    "lastMod": "12.01.2022 23:20:32",
    "size": 136437512,
    "fileType": ".exe"
}]
```

the class method returns:

```
 List<MyFileData> list = new(MyFileData){*method getting files*}
 return list;
```

and if grouped:

```
 foreach(string fileExtension in fileExtensions)
    {
        IEnumerable<MyFileData> query =
             from file in allFiles
             where file.FileType == fileExtension
             select file;

        sortedFiles.Add(new MyFileData{
            FileType = fileExtension });
        sortedFiles.AddRange(query.ToList());
    }
        
    return sortedFiles;
```

I need a hint how to make custom output with LINQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `GroupBy()` method (see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-6.0)).

Assuming you have this:

```
var myFileDatas = new List<MyFileData>
{
    new MyFileData { Name = "codeblocks-20.03mingw-setup.exe", FileType = ".exe", LastMod = "13.03.2022 22:57:47", Size = 152419674 },
    new MyFileData { Name = "DiscordSetup.exe", FileType = ".exe", LastMod = "16.01.2022 13:16:06", Size = 82973864 },
    new MyFileData { Name = "Abc.zip", FileType = ".zip", LastMod = "01.01.2022 13:16:06", Size = 82973864 }
};
```

...the following line results in two groups.

```
var result = myFileDatas.GroupBy(x => x.FileType);
```

The group with key `".zip"` has 1 entry and the group with `".exe"` has two entries.

Comment: Two more examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq) with both, fluent and query syntax.

Comment: About 1st part, I'm still getting all class properties, but I would like to omit the "FileType", this approach does not solve the problem

Comment: @KubaJ Then you can use .Select() method and map each group to either a anonymous type (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/anonymous-types) or another class you will need to create.